# getting error GestureRecognizer with UIImageview in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

i am using 20 uiimageview so i have given tag value of each imageview

now i want to add  GestureRecognizer on each image view

```
for index in 0 ... fields.count - 1{


            let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldsTappedAction")
            gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            println(fields[index])
            fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


        }
```

now i am trying to get tag using  fieldsTappedAction

```
 func fieldsTappedAction (recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){


        let tappedField = recognizer.view as! TTTImageView
        tappedField.setPlayer(currectPlayer)
}
```

but its not working when i taped imageview getting app crashed in the time of tap.

```
fieldsTapped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc95a4abf90
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector has arguments so needs a colon after its name. So:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldsTappedAction:")
```